# mysql get records with relation in usable structure

Tags: php, mysql, database

Say I have 2 tables. `parent` & `child` where a parent can have many children.

I want to get the data in the following structure so:

```
[
  { parent_id:1, children: [{child_id: 1, parent_id:1},{ child_id:2, parent_id:1}],
  { parent_id:2, children: [{child_id: 3, parent_id:2},{ child_id:4, parent_id:2}],
  { parent_id:3, children: [{child_id: 5, parent_id:3},{ child_id:6, parent_id:3}]
]
```

`JOIN` gives me duplicate parent data for each child, and `GROUP BY parent_id` only gives me 1 child per parent.

Currently my solution is: `SELECT * from parent` loop through the results and then `SELECT * FROM child WHERE parent_id = :parent_id`. I feel there has to be a better way.

Is MySQL capable of performing this in fewer queries, if so how would I go about it?

---

**EDIT**: *Hacky solution* based on using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
$q = "SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.id,'|#|', c.column_2, '|#|', c.column3, '|#|', c.column4 SEPARATOR '###') AS children
FROM parent p
INNER JOIN child c ON p.id = c.parent_id";

$parents= query($q);
foreach ($parents as &$parent) {
  $children = explode('###', $parent->children);
  foreach ($children as &$child){
    $child = array_combine(['id','col1','col2','col3'], explode('|#|', $child));
  }
  $parent->children = $children;
}
```

Essentially get the string with separators, explode into records, then explode into columns and remap the column values with hardcoded column names.

Leaving this open to tidier solutions.

**If there are no better solutions, which would be more efficient.**

- 1 query:`group_concat` where `php` manipulates the data into the desired structure.
- n* queries: get all parents, then loop through them and get each parents children.
- 2 queries: get all parents, get all children, loop through and map them (currently using this)

Comment: maybe Group_concat can help you

Comment: Thanks Jens, i've provided a solution using `group_concat` it works, but it certainly isn't pretty.

Comment: Hello, I think You cannot make this type of structure with the single query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT p.parent_id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.child_id) AS childs
FROM parent p
JOIN child c
ON p.parent_id = c.parent_id
GROUP BY p.parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this just puts all the data into in one cell name `childs` there are no identifiers or way to distinguish multiple columns from `child`. I think using `SEPARATOR` may start to get messy